# Does Marmite keep away mosquitoes?

Tags: natural-remedies, entomology

I saw this rather weak claim in this [BBC news article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-13541148):

> Several newspapers, including the Guardian, the Sun and the Daily Telegraph, have claimed the yeasty spread to be the perfect defence against mozzies.

Is there any good evidence that this is the case?

Comment: The UK has mosquitoes? I thought that'd be more of an Australian issue!

Comment: @Andrew yes we do...

Comment: @Oddthinking: What's wrong with the yeast-extract tag?

Comment: I asked myself the question "Would anyone ever use this tag for searching or for monitoring? Or is it just noise?" I thought the latter. Do you disagree?

Comment: It repels humans! Surely it must work for mosquitoes.